# How to parse a wkt Geometrycollection with Boost::Geometry?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry, wkt

I'm new to boost::geometry and can't find any examples in the documentation or here for this.
I have a text file with wkt GEOMETRYCOLLECTION on each line. Every collection holds one or more MULTIPOINTS.
Parsing MULTIPOINTS is no problem:

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::point<double, 3, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::multi_point<point> multipoint;
multipoint myPoints;
boost::geometry::read_wkt("MULTIPOINT ((123456.123 1234567.123 42.42), (654321.123 7654321.123 123.12))", myPoints);
// do something with myPoints
for (auto &point : myPoints) {
  std::cout << point.get<0>() << " " << point.get<1>() << " " << point.get<2>() << std::endl;
}
```

But I need to parse something like this:

```
bg::read_wkt("GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTIPOINT ((1 2 3), (3 2 1)), MULTIPOINT ((4 5 6), (7 8 9)))", myCollection);
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be the variant (a collection of Boost.Variant's), but it is not yet fully implemented, only a few algorithms support the variant.

Comment: Thank you. Any roadmap or date planned when/if this will be implemented?

Comment: @baal There is no exact timeline, but we've been slowly working on variant geometries. So, you'd need to check the source code out of the trunk and see what is missing what works for you.